# pandas dynamically identify header row - Combine multiple xlsx files

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, list

I have 10 excel sheets and each sheet is expected to the same header/column names.

Files are named as `ABC.xlsx`, `DEF_123.xlsx` etc. There is no naming wildcard pattern in excel filenames.

My problem is, some excel files have header appearing in the 1st row itself. whereas for some excel files it may appear in 2nd row (1st row is empty) and for some files it may appear in 5th row (first 4 rows are empty).

My objective is to do the below

a) Combine/vertically stack the data from each excel file into one dataframe

So, I tried the below

```
record_counts = []
dfs=[]
folder_path = Path.cwd()
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(str(folder_path)+"\*.xlsx"))

for f in filenames:
    filename = os.path.basename(f)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)
    header_row = 0
    if df.iloc[0].isna().all():
        header_row = 1
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=header_row)
    count = len(df.index)
    record_counts.append(count)
    dfs.append(df)
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

But the above code assumes that headers appear in either first row (0th location). If not, then we look at 1st location (2nd row). But this is hardcoding.

How can I identify the row where header appears dynamically and take the data from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just a proper logic to identify the first non-empty row:

```
record_counts = []
dfs=[]
folder_path = Path.cwd()
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(str(folder_path)+"\*.xlsx"))

for f in filenames:
    filename = os.path.basename(f)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=None)
    
    # Identify the header row as the first non-empty row
    header_row = df.apply(lambda row: row.notnull().any(), axis=1).idxmax()

    # Set the selected row as the header
    df.columns = df.iloc[header_row]

    # Drop the rows before the header row
    df = df.iloc[header_row + 1:]
    dfs.append(df)
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
import os
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

record_counts = []
dfs = []
folder_path = Path.cwd()
filenames = sorted(glob.glob(str(folder_path) + "/*.xlsx"))

def find_header_row(df):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if 'ColumnName' in row.values:  
            return i
    return 0

for f in filenames:
    filename = os.path.basename(f)
    df_temp = pd.read_excel(f, header=None)
    header_row = find_header_row(df_temp)
    
    df = pd.read_excel(f, header=header_row)
    count = len(df.index)
    record_counts.append(count)
    dfs.append(df)
    
combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find another way to solve this by identifying the `first valid index`

```
for f in filenames:
    filename = os.path.basename(f)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename,header=None,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    header_row = df.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index()).min()
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, header=header_row,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    count = len(df.index)
    record_counts.append(count)
    print(f"{filename}: {count} records")
    dfs.append(df)
```

This helped me identify the first non-empty row